# Thousands of ad requests but no impressions in Meta Audience Network

Tags: android, flutter, facebook, ads, facebook-monetization-manager

I have integrated Meta Audience Network in my app (built with flutter). Since 2 weeks I can see thousands of requests (in fact 800k last week) but there are no impression being counted. I am unable to figure out why this is happening.

Can anyone please help me in this case. I am getting test ads successfully while testing Meta Audience. But in production I am only getting too many requests but no impressions (as you can see in the image below).[image]

Comment: Meta only uses bidding & no more supports waterfall. One of the things that could be possible is that Meta is losing bids & hence no impressions. Ofc. zero impressions to 800K requests is not something one would see usually. Have you tried using `Ads Inspector` & checking if you are getting real ads after selecting Meta as the only Ad provider?

Comment: @Darshan thanks for posting your opinion. I am really new to meta. I was using AdMob earlier. I think meta supports waterfall because they have option of waterfall in their dashboard. And I am successfully getting test ads but in production I am facing this issue.

Comment: As per the docs, only Bidding is supported: https://developers.google.com/admob/android/mediation/meta

Comment: Hi @Darshan thanks for sharing this link. This is just about mediation of FAN with AdMob. But I am using FAN without Admob.

FAN = Facebook Audience Network.

And by the way FAN is now showing ads. My app was not approved at that time which was the reason behind too many ad requests but no fill. Thanks for giving me suggestions.

Comment: Check the ad unit for any violation

Comment: @SyedWaleed I am facing the same problem with Admob and FAN mediation.  Currently, my app is under extended review. Will I be seeing impressions once the review is done by the FAN team?

Answer (score 1):

Please check your account is verified or not, sometimes it is not showing impression for that reason

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34738566)

Comment: Yeah this was one of the reasons.